# Why doesn't following java code throw java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when there is no element present at index 1?

Tags: java, string

```
String str="x";
System.out.println(str.substring(1));
```

From Javadoc:

> `String java.lang.String.substring(int beginIndex)`: Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The **substring begins with the character at the specified index** and extends to the end of this string.

Comment: Because it's perfectly defined, it's the suffix of the array after the 0 element, which is an empty string.

Comment: @Turing85 Why is this code not throwing any exception? Only element present in the specified string is at index 0 and I'm trying to get element at index 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)), and pay specific attention to the "emptiness" example:

```
Returns a string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins
with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of
this string. 

Examples: 

 "unhappy".substring(2) returns "happy"
 "Harbison".substring(3) returns "bison"
 "emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)

Parameters:
beginIndex the beginning index, inclusive.
Returns:
the specified substring.
Throws:
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than
                            the length of this String object
```

An exception is throw `if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object`; in your case, beginIndex is equal to the length of your string, and not larger.